# CakePHP 2.0 User Model:How to validate more than one action

Tags: model-view-controller, validation, model, cakephp-2.0

how to validate more actions in any view like createing an user or editig.
Want to have more different rules in different actions.

i use my validation in my Model as an example like this:

```
<?

    App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');

    class User extends AppModel {

        public $name        = 'User';

        public $primaryKey  = 'id';

        public $validate    = array(

            'username'  => array(  
                'first'=>array(
                    'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                    'message'=>'Your username is empty!',
                    'last'=>true
                ),
                'second'=>array(
                    'rule'=>'isUnique',
                    'message'=>'the username is already taken!'
                )
            ),

            'password'  => array(
                'rule'      => 'notEmpty',
                'message'   => 'Your password is empty!'
            )

        );



        public function beforeSave() {

            if(isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
                $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
            }
            return true;
        }

    }

?>
```

but i have different actions where i want to use the validation in other way like:

```
        'username'  => array(  
            'first'=>array(
                'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                'message'=>'Your username is empty!',
                'last'=>true
            ),
            'second'=>array(
                'rule'=>array('minlength',5),
                'message'=>'The Username is to short!'
            )
        ),

        'password'  => array(
            'rule'      => 'notEmpty',
            'message'   => 'Your password is empty!'
        )

    );
```

in the same Model and for the same Controller is this possible.

Comment: Your question makes no sense and there are no details. What code are you currently using and what does it not do that you are trying to do?

Comment: hope this will help for better understanding

Answer (score 1):

I found another soltution somthing else by searching again and read the documatation step by step.

here the link to the option: [on](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#on)

this help too because you can distinguish between **update** and **create** with this option.

Example from Model:

```
public $validate    = array(

        'username'  => array(  
            'first'  =>array(
                'rule'      =>'notEmpty',
                'message'   =>'Sie haben den Produktnamen nicht eingetragen!',
                'last'      =>true,
                'on'        =>'update'
            ),
            'second' =>array(
                'on'        => 'create',
                'rule'      =>'isUnique',
                'message'   =>'Der Username ist bereits vergeben!'
            ),
        ));
```

i didn´t try it yet but think this should work

Answer (score 1):

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/dardosordi/2008/07/29/multivalidatablebehavior-using-many-validation-rulesets-per-model

You can use the behavior in the link above to use something like this:

In your Model:

```
var $actsAs = array('Multivalidatable'); 

var $validate = array( 
          //your default validation set here
);

var $validationSets = array(
      'firstSet' => array(
                //your first set of validation rules here
                          ),
      'secondSet' => array(
                //your second set of validation rules here
                            ));
```

Then in your Controller before the Save action select your appropriate validation set

```
 $this->Modelname->setValidation('firstSet');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for clarifying your question. Now that I understand what you are asking, this is a good question.

I'm not sure if this is possible and don't have time to test today, but since the `$validate` variable is public, then you should be able to set it in the controller as needed.  Therefore, you should be able to create rule arrays on the fly or you could simple assign predefined rule arrays that you have built in your model.

```
$validationRulesOne = array(
    //Create the first set of validation rules
);

$validationRulesTwo = array(
    //Create the second set of validation rules
);
```

Then, in your controller action, set the validation set before calling the validator;

```
//Action 1
$this->User->validate = $validationRulesOne;
$this->User->validate();

//Action 2
$this->User->validate = $validationRulesTwo;
$this->User->validate();
```

Comment: no it isn´t working it must working but other way but i don´t know how... to solve this,the variable aren´t defined anywhere in the controller thats first why it won´t work what i can do is to validate everytime from controller but i do want keep all in one area in the Model that would be cool when it would work. Thats the infos i´ve got from the cakephp site ["controller validate"](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html)
["model validate"](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html)

Comment: Set the validation arrays in your model.  Then in the controller, change the validation array based on which set of rules you want to use.  If you need to dynamically create rules, then create a function in your model that will build a rules array and then apply it to the validate variable.